# Converting Next.js - Javascript code to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am in the process of converting my Javascript code to TypeScript for a web application I am making on top of Next.Js

The following is my converted code:

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';

interface FormData {
  email: string;
}

interface MessageStatus {
  message?: string; 
  success?: boolean;
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  error: string;
}

const EmailSubmissionComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({email: ''});
  const [messageStatus, setMessageStatus] = useState<MessageStatus>({});

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSumbit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; //Should remove if not testing locally. 
    event.preventDefault();

    if (formData.email != "") {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('REDACTED', { //Change for production
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        });
  
        console.log('Response:', response); // Log response
        if (response.ok) {
          const responseBody = await response.json();
          // console.log('Response Body:', responseBody);
          setMessageStatus({message: "", success: true})
          // console.log('Form submitted successfully');
        } else {
          const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = await response.json(); 
          setMessageStatus({message:errorResponse.error, success:false})
          console.error('Form submission failed');
        }
      } catch (error :any) {
        setMessageStatus({message: "Network Error: Please try again shortly", success: false})
        console.log("Printing Errors:", error.message);
  
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:w-[600px]">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row">
        <input type="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="E-mail Address" className="sm:flex items-stretch flex-grow focus:outline-none block rounded-lg sm:rounded-none sm:rounded-l-lg pl-4 py-2"></input>
        
        <button type="submit" className="sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto sm:-ml-2 py-2 px-2 rounded-lg font-medium text-white focus:outline-none bg-logo-blue">
          Stay in the Loop
        </button>
        
      </form>
      {messageStatus.message && <div className="border-2 rounded border-red-700 bg-red-300 py-2 px-2 mt-1">
        {messageStatus.message}</div>}
      {messageStatus.success && <div className="border-2 rounded border-green-700 bg-green-300 py-2 px-2 mt-1">
        Congrats! You have signed up. Stay Tuned!</div>}
    </div>
  );

}

export default EmailSubmissionComponent;
```

I have addressed all type related error.
I am still getting syntax errors around the HTML code I have written in the return block.

For Reference the below is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Through some research I have come across solutions that relate to the tsconfig.json file and setting the jsx property to be "react", but then running `npm run dev` I get the below message:

[image]

Any guidance on why I am getting a syntax error at my HTML code when doing this conversation would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When asking for help on how to resolve any error, it is prudent to provide others the exact error details.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into a typescript playground, I do not get any syntax errors https://tsplay.dev/w1LBXW. Please describe the actual problem you are having. What does the error say, _exactly_?

Comment: Apologies, The original post has been updated with the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 2):

Enable [jsx](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx) in tsconfig.json add this line:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "jsx": "react"
}
```

--- **Edit** ---

`"jsx": "preserve"` should also work

This is what my tsconfig.json looks like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },

  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: I did do that but when running the the code through npm run dev Next.js converts the field back to preserve and states the following:

 We detected TypeScript in your project and reconfigured your tsconfig.json file for you. Strict-mode is set to false by default.
   The following mandatory changes were made to your tsconfig.json:

        - jsx was set to preserve (next.js implements its own optimized jsx transform)

Comment: It appears that Next.js is overriding the configuration. I believe the root of your issue could be related to include in tsconfig. Please ensure that your put your config in the question. You can also try adding the following lines to explicitly include: `include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"]`

Comment: I just included my config file in the question.  I have those include statements present already.

Comment: Your config looks good, If you cannot reproduce this in typescript playground I cannot tell you for sure what your problem might be, I can give you another suggestion: try restarting typescript in vscode and also try running in in terminal "yarn tsc --noEmit"

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I wrote the file extension for the react files to be ".ts" but it should be a ".tsx" extension for react components.

From the react docs:

[image]

I hope this will save someone else alot of time when converting a project from JavaScript to TypeScript.